# Correct Way To Prepare pg Query

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, pg

I have been trying to prepare a query to update rows in my table for certain user(s) I am using Node js and the npm package [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg). The problem is arising when I run the query my error message will return error:

> syntax error at or near "VALUES", or "WHERE"

but never giving more context of the error making it hard to pinpoint. I have tried re-arranging the values and trying different approaches but have been unsuccessful.

```
populateProfileData(username, gender, dob, country, province, city, date, user_id) {
    console.log('================' + username + gender + dob + country + province + city + date + user_id);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
        client.connect()
            .then(() => console.log('connected'))
            .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
        // This Works ---> UPDATE users SET dob = '032018' WHERE USER_id = 15
        const text = 'UPDATE users SET(username, dob, country, province, city, date)  WHERE user_id = (user_id) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)';
        const values = [username, dob, country, province, city, date, user_id]
        const query = client.query(text, values)
            .then(success => {
                console.log('ran query')
                resolve(success);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('--------' + error)
                reject(error);
            })
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Your query syntax is messed up, i.e. `WHERE user_id = (user_id)` does not represent anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For UPDATE a some records you must have indexed identification column[s] to use its for search existing rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, username, dob, country, province, city, date) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Joe', 1, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  (2, 'Doe', 2, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  ...
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET 
  username=EXCLUDED.username,
  dob=EXCLUDED.dob,
  country=EXCLUDED.country,
  province=EXCLUDED.province,
  city=EXCLUDED.city,
  date=EXCLUDED.date;
```

2. instead update existing rows you can simle ignore its:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, username, dob, country, province, city, date) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Joe', 1, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  (2, 'Doe', 2, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  ...
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO NOTHING
```

3. when your table have a constraints, you must disable its before update and turn on after all update ended:

```sql
ALTER "country" DROP NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO users (id, username, dob, country, province, city, date) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'Joe', 1, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  (2, 'Doe', 2, 'usa', 'utah', 'odessa', '12-21-2015'),
  ...
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET 
  username=EXCLUDED.username,
  dob=EXCLUDED.dob,
  country=EXCLUDED.country,
  province=EXCLUDED.province,
  city=EXCLUDED.city,
  date=EXCLUDED.date;
ALTER "country" SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That's pretty descriptive and addressed my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about that module, but the syntax of update statement is something like this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET
  username = $1, 
  dob = $2, 
  country = $3, 
  province = $4, 
  city = $5, 
  date = $6
WHERE 
  user_id = $7
```

So hopefully this will get you closer to a working code

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to get it going taking your answer into consideration and to update the db from the POST from the client. I'm going to hold off on marking your answer right now; reason being, I would like to see the proper way how to do this with pg module in my particular use case but nevertheless thank you for getting me on the right track!